# Argparse with set_usage function

Tags: python-2.7, argparse, optparse

Does argparse module in Python have an alternative for set_usage function like in optparse module?
When I run

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.set_usage('')
```

It returns

```
 myClass has no attribute set_usage
```

Answer (score 0):

With `argparse`, you can [set the `usage` string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage) by passing it as an argument to `ArgumentParser`:

**script.py:**

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='MYPROG',
    usage='%(prog)s arrg',
    description='Very informative description')

parser.print_help()
```

Running `script.py` yields

```
usage: MYPROG arrg

Very informative description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: How to add this if I am using self. Like self.set_usage() in optparse. When I was using optparse I did self.set_usage(''). How to do this in argparse?

Comment: What is `self`? Is it the same as `parser`?

Comment: Yes it is under a class. self is the object. 
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__(self, **kwargs)

Comment: You could use `self.usage = ...`, or you could simply pass the `usage` argument to `ArgumentParser.__init__`. For example, `kwargs['usage'] = ...` followed by `argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__(self, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

This interactive demo shows two ways of setting the usage.  'usage' is an attribute of the parser object.  If it is the default `None`, then the parser constructs the usage from the arguments.  Otherwise it uses the value that has been set.

Normally you would set it via an initialization parameter.  But Python gives you to the freedom to set or change attributes directly.

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='test usage')

In [3]: print parser
ArgumentParser(prog='ipython', usage='test usage', description=None, version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)

In [4]: parser.usage
Out[4]: 'test usage'

In [5]: parser.usage = 'alternate usage'

In [6]: print parser.format_help()
usage: alternate usage

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The usage isn't the only attribute that can be set directly:

```
In [13]: parser.prog='PROG'

In [14]: parser.usage = '%(prog)s: alternate usage'

In [15]: print parser.format_usage()
usage: PROG: alternate usage
```

The `set_usage()` method in `optparse` does little more than `self.usage = usage`.  Look it up in the `Lib/optparse.py` file.